# OneDrive API search based on a keyword gives only section information and doesnot give any information about page details

Tags: graph, onenote

I want to know the page id or page url which has paternity in the content. When i use search functionality, i get the section details but i don't get any information about page.

Query:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='paternity')

Result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:06:28Z",
            "id": "dfhsdfkhfklsdfsdkjf",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:20:26Z",
            "name": "Section1.one",
            "webUrl": "https://microsoft-my.sharepoint.com/personal/abcd_contoso_com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B7E1C4305-983D-4CE2-A15E-DBAF1B961423%7D&file=Section1.one&action=default&DefaultItemOpen=1",
            "size": 390328,
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "abcd@contoso.com",
                    "displayName": "abcd"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "abcd@contoso.com",
                    "displayName": "abcd"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "b!QqRkFzhjsdgjkdhfkjdhXiDBfhDiNEmqz4NJGbg-Gcv-NrFDvVRJca8R9-3ylQ",
                "driveType": "business",
                "id": "01QsdjhdkjhdsdkjhHGT4FXINN2A"
            },
            "file": {
                "mimeType": "application/msonenote"
            },
            "fileSystemInfo": {
                "createdDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:06:28Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-07-11T11:20:26Z"
            },
            "searchResult": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Please advise on how to get page level information

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote API has search  - you may try using that one:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2014/11/17/introducing-the-onenote-search-api-beta-powered-by-bing/

Comment: Thanks Jorge.. I was wondering if this beta version would be moving into production without any change so that i can use the same api's for my application.

Comment: The blog is outdated now, search is part of Graph now, which you can experiment with at developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, and you can find info on the search operation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content#supported-odata-query-string-options